# How to list specific oauth2Permissions using azure cli

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I was trying to get only few scopes/oauthPermissions  from Microsoft Graph. And
I am able to get the specific permissions only using this code

```
$appPerms =@()
$appPerms += "AttackSimulation.Read.All"
$appPerms += "Acronym.Read.All"
$appPerms += "ReportSettings.ReadWrite.All"
$msGraphService = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'"
#Write-Host $msGraphService.AppRoles
$permissions = $msGraphService.AppRoles.Where({$_.Value -in $appPerms})
```

But I need this suing azure cli command. I have tried something like this, but didn't work.

```
$permissionIds = az ad sp list --filter "displayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'" --query '[].oauth2Permissions[?value=="openid,email"].{Value:value, Id:id, UserConsentDisplayName:userConsentDisplayName}' -o table
Write-Host $permissionIds
```

Is there anyway to get only 2 or more specific oauth2Permissions using azure cli?

Edit

I am able to get single permission using this command.

```
 $userRead = az ad sp show --id $graphId --query "oauth2Permissions[?value=='User.Read'].id | [0]"
```

How can I use it for returning multiple ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days brainstorming I found one work around.  With this I am able to reduce the multiple calls to the Azure like this,

> ```
> $userRead = az ad sp show --id $graphId --query "oauth2Permissions[?value=='User.Read'].id | [0]"
> $email = az ad sp show --id $graphId --query "oauth2Permissions[?value=='email'].id | [0]"
> $profile = az ad sp show --id $graphId --query "oauth2Permissions[?value=='profile'].id | [0]"
> ```

Instead of adding the above call multiple times, I tried something like this.

Steps I followed

1. Fetch the graph id ($GraphAppId)
2. Saved all the oauth2Permissions in
3. Json format to a variable From the result I collected the required

   ```
   $GraphAppId = az ad sp list --query '[?appDisplayName==''Microsoft Graph''].appId' -o tsv --all
   $permissionIds = az ad sp show --id $GraphAppId --query "oauth2Permissions[].{Value : value, Id:id}" | ConvertFrom-Json
   $permissionIds.Where{ $_.Value -eq 'email' }.id
   $permissionIds.Where{ $_.Value -eq 'profile' }.id
   ```

now I don't need to call multiple times for getting the required scopes/permission ids.

And the output would be

```
64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0
14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1
```

Please share if there are some elegant ways than this.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory cmdlet requests require an authenticate account, we need to run the below command

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

As you have already got the `oauth2Permissions` for one ObjectID. We need to get the ObjectID's and loop.

To fetch the  `ObjectID` of the Azure AD Applications, run the below command.

```cs
Get-AzADServicePrincipal
```

[image]

Next, loop the object id's in the command

```cs
Connect-AzureAD
$result=@()  
$ObjID = Get-AzADServicePrincipal 
foreach($Object in $OA){
 $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
           OuthPerm=  az ad sp show --id $Object.Id --query "oauth2Permissions[?value=='User.Read'].id | [0]" 
     
}
    $result += $obj
}
$result
```

Comment: Actually I want to accomplish this using azure cli command.

Comment: To get objectid in CLI, use `az ad user  list`

Comment: I wanted to avoid multiple calls to the azure for getting each Ids, or getting all Ids , instead I need to get some specific ids only from the call for example, profile, openid, user.read  like this. I have tried like I mentioned in the question.  `az ad sp list --filter "displayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'" ...... `  but didn't work

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to tackle the issue. If you have some other suggestions please share. Thanks for your efforts